# Android Studio: How to bring back the outline window on the right side of the program?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I am currently learning how to make Android apps, using a textbook to guide me through some basic apps. The text teaches you how to change the layout and layout properties via the "Outline" window, but it appears that the outline window is either hidden or has been replaced by the "Component Tree" window. Is there a way to bring back the Outline window?

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 on Windows 10.
Textbook is called "Android for Programmers: An App-Driven Approach, 2/e"

Thanks!

Comment: Outline window or properties window? Post a print screen, that should be hard to find where to click

Comment: Can you post a screenshot along with the question..?

Comment: I don't know of an "outline" window in Studio.  There is one in Eclipse, however.  Are you sure you're working entirely in Studio?

Comment: Just looking at a errata page: http://www.deitel.com/bookresources/androidfp2/Androidfp_02_p38-50.pdf it does look like the book was using the old Android Development Tools which was Eclipse based.

Comment: Is the Outline view the one with all the methods? In Android Studio, that is called "Structure".

Answer (score 13):

The [outline view](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcoutline.htm) in old eclipse-based Android Studio versions is not a part of itellij used in modern Android Studio, and its functionality is replaced by other components.

#### for layouts and layout XML

The component panel in more recent Android Studio builds replaces the outline view. The properties associated with an element are shown in a tree view just below the component list when viewing a layout.

#### for code

*Alt+7* Structure view will produce a docked window on the left side (replacing the project tree) that shows the structure of the code.

#### for /res/values/strings.xml specifically

Unfortunately they didn't create a resources view that works in general (that I am aware of), but the strings.xml file has a translation assistance that you can open by clicking "open editor" which does add a gui to the XML.

Comment: Correction: Alt+7, not Alt+F7

Comment: on a mac it is cmd + 7

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, a component tree is available in the bottom left hand corner of the Palette. I think that this is functionally equivalent to the Outline in Eclipse.

[image: Component Tree in Android Studio]